# Magento 2 - How to get value in "core_config_data" table

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

In magento 2, how to get value in `core_config_data` table.

Anyone know, show me step by step.Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to inject the an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` in your block.

```
$protected $scopeConfig;
protected $storeManager; 
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;  
    ....
}
```

Then create the method `getStoreName()`

```
public function getStoreName()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/store_information/name',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId()
 );
}
```

and call in your template `echo $this->getStoreName()`

Answer (score 10):

First you need to include the `Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface` class in your constructor:

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
     ...
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface $scopeInterface,
     ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeInterface;
    ...
}
```

Then in your class' method you can call the following:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('path/of/config', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: $this->scopeConfig->getValue() must be in multi line because as Magento2 EcgM2 standard show error "Line exceeds 120 characters".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig`, In your constructor argument and create an Object `$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig`;

Now, you can get config value as below:

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('path of config', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

For more details, check these:

http://magehelper.blogspot.in/2015/06/get-system-config-values-in-magento-2.html
https://maxyek.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/building-magento-2-extension-extendedconfig/